# php storing tamil in php mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

**njhw]wf;fpuk Muha]r]rpa[k]/ rpj]j kUj]Jt tuyhWk]

1). "hdpfSf;F ,y]yhjJ vJ>
m). r";rpj fd]kk]   m{). m{fhkpa fd]kk]   ,). gpuhuj]jf] fd]kk]   <). ,tw]wpy] vJt[kpy]iy.

2). ‘,iwtdpy] ,Ue]jy]y/ khiaapy] ,Ue]J jhd; cyfk] cw]gj;jpahfpd;wJ’ – ahh] bfhs]if
        m). irt-rpe]jhe;jpfs;   m{). m{rPtfthjpfs;   ,). rkzh]fs;   <). ntjhe]jpfs;.
**

The above ia typed in tamil-aishwarya font.

**I need to know how to store it in php mysql database**

Plz reply if anyone know the answer

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://rafeekphp.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/multi-language-support-in-mysql/) a tutorial that goes into this.

Comment: I have seen the above link Ólafur Waage, It is working for this tamil senetence "இந்தியா நாட்டின் பக்கங்கள்" But how to apply for other documents in tamil

Answer (score 1):

If you have it in font types such as TAB, TAM etc, First you have to convert it into Unicode.  You can do that here: http://www.jaffnalibrary.com/tools/Unicode.htm

Also, You have set up the character set of your tables or fields to Unicode.

Comment: The link is not available. Try [Puthuvai  Unicode Writer](http://www.suratha.com/unicode.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to set-up your DB to store UTF-8 strings and then save your work in Unicode.. dont try fonts like Bamini. Now Unicode is widely accepted standard.

Answer (score 0):

You may need the unicode support.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Just store it as such? A database in the end stores bits. It won't store the font used to display those bits. You will get the same bits out when you ask later, and at that time you can reuse the same font.

Of course, a more sensible solution in general is the use of Unicode, but I understand that the Unicode people and Tamil aren't really getting along well.